# EclipseLink batch-writing : custom composite key instead of @GeneratedValue?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, eclipselink

## Question

Can EclipseLink's `batch-writing` be used if the entities to be persisted do not use `@GeneratedValue` for their primary keys?

I have `@IdClass` to use a composite key, and the values are assigned during the instantiation in the code.

#### Example

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "myentity")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@IdClass(MyIdClass.class)
public class MyEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(updatable = false)
  private String foo;

  @Id
  @Column(updatable = false)
  private String bar;

  @Column
  private String whatever;
}
```

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class MyIdClass implements Serializable {

  private String foo;
  private String bar;
}
```

## Context

So far, I've been unable to activate EclipseLink's `batch-writing`; I just can't get the configuration right.

The few bits of documentation I find online usually seem to mention that it's important to **not** use `@GeneratedValue` with the `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, and usually suggest to use one of the two other `GenerationType` strategies. However, they don't seem to specifically mention that it's possible to get this to work without using *any* strategy.

Comment: They don't mention it because it wasn't thought to be worth mentioning - if your case didn't work, batch writing itself wouldn't work for anyone. IDENTITY generation and sequencing itself gets in the way of batching only because it requires getting the value from the statement or immediately after the statement directly, which is hard to figure out when a statement could consist of 50 inserts, and is driver dependent if it is even possible to do. Anything that has ids assigned beforehand (preallocation or just no sequencing) is fine. What is the issues you are seeing?

Comment: @Chris Well, in the first place, I'm not entirely certain how to make sure that `batch-writing` ever got activated properly. What are the expected symptoms in the logs? Would `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` in `application.properties` still end up showing individual `INSERT` statements, or would I see batched statements with a big array for my `bind` properties?

Comment: Then does the order ever matter in terms of the queries? I have an entity with a `@OneToOne` relationship that needs to be persisted (they both need to get `upsert` in the DB). For example, I'm currently trying out two options: **1)** `entityManager#merge`. For each entity, The `merge` issues one `SELECT` statement first and then 2 `INSERT` (one for the entity, and another one for the OneToOne entity): am I supposed to try to order this properly?

Comment: **2)** bulk delete with a `@Query` + trigger in the DB to delete the other associated entity + `JPArepository#saveAll`. For this second option, I'm mostly wondering about how `saveAll` would work with the `batch-writing` considering the OneToOne: am I again supposed to somehow try to order my `INSERT`s so that maybe the OneToOnes are all saved first ?

Comment: Order matters, yes, but JPA providers will order the inserts/updates/deletes within a transaction - they don't follow the order you've called persist or merge, unless you are calling something that causes a flush in between. If you call merge on the same entity type a few times, EclipseLink should group the inserts/updates appropriately when the transaction commits or is flushed. What do you see in the logs for the statements and their ordering? For option 2, bulk deletes force a flush of everything in the context.

Comment: @Chris are you a maintainer of EclipseLink? I've seen you answering EL questions all over the place on SO. Would it be possible to chat? (Just provide an SO Chat link.)

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239322/eclipselink I'm listed as a committer, but haven't been actively contributing code for some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris said in the comments:

> They don't mention it because it wasn't thought to be worth mentioning

So basically: yes, it works just fine.